# The "hash" in "hash out the details "

Tags: meaning, etymology, idioms

What does "hash" mean here, where does it come from- meaning to discuss, work out, iron out something- especially the details of something- until an agreement is reached.

Examples (taken from various dictionaries)

The department was hashing out the new syllabus.

I need to hash this matter over with you.

I'll call my mother to hash out to details of the Christmas dinner.

They met during the day to hash out  the campaign's reaction to the controversy.

The detectives hashed out their theories about who committed the murder.

They've spent quite a bit of time hashing over the problem.

We need to sit down and hash things out.

Comment: It's a figurative extension of the literal verb meaning: *To cut (meat) into small pieces for cooking; to make into a hash.*

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/origin-of-hashing-out-plans

Comment: Agree. It's definitely a duplicate.